# How to remove inline styling of copied content from webpage using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

For example I have copied some content/paragraph from wikipedia and then i want to paste code in my webpage dynamically but it's showing lot of inline styles. I want clean and need proper html format of code. I tried many ways but it's removing all the tags either i want to remove only extra inline styles and extra tags. Sample code i'm placing here. Please help me anyone to achieve this.

Sample Code:

```
&amp;lt;span style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;In 1896 and named after its inventor,&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georges-Fernand_Widal" title="Georges-Fernand Widal" style="color: rgb(11, 0, 128); background-image: none; background-position: initial; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; fot-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;Georges-Fernand Widal&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;, is a presumptive&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serological" class="mw-redirect" title="Serological" style="color: rgb(11, 0, 128); background-image: none; background-position: initial; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;serological&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;&amp;amp;nbsp;testfor&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enteric_fever" class="mw-redirect" title="Enteric fever" style="color: rgb(11, 0, 128); background-image: none; background-position: initial; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;enteric fever&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;&amp;amp;nbsp;or&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undulant_fever" class="mw-redirect" title="Undulant fever" style="color: rgb(11, 0, 128); background-image: none; background-position: initial; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;undulant fever&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;&amp;amp;nbsp;whereby bacteria causing tphoid and protozoa causing malaria fever are mixed with a serum containing specific antibodies obtained from an infected individual. In cases of&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;i style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salmonella" title="Salmonella" style="color: rgb(11, 0, 128); background-image: none; background-position: initial;"&amp;gt;Salmonella&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/i&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;&amp;amp;nbsp;infection, it is a demonstration of the presence of O-soma false-positive result. Test results need to be interpreted carefully to account for any history of enteric fever,&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typhoid" class="mw-redirect" title="Typhoid" style="color: rgb(11, 0, 128); background-image: none; background-position: initial; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;typhoid&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;&amp;amp;nbsp;vaccination, and the general level of antibodies in the populations in endemic areas of the world.&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typhidot" title="Typhidot" style="color: rgb(11, 0, 128); background-image: none; background-position: initial; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;Typhidot&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;&amp;amp;nbsp;is the other test used to ascertain the diagnosis of&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typhoid_fever" title="Typhoid fever" style="color: rgb(11, 0, 128); background-image: none; background-position: initial; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;typhoid fever&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;. As with all serological tests, the rise in antibody levels needed to perform the diagnosis takes 7–14 days, which limits its applicability in early diagnosis. Other means of diagnosing&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;i style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salmonella_typhi" class="mw-redirect" title="Salmonella typhi" style="color: rgb(11, 0, 128); background-image: none; background-position: initial;"&amp;gt;Salmonella typhi&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/i&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;&amp;amp;nbsp;(and&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;i style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salmonella_paratyphi" class="mw-redirect" title="Salmonella paratyphi" style="color: rgb(11, 0, 128); background-image: none; background-position: initial;"&amp;gt;paratyphi&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/i&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;) include cultures of blood, urine and&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faeces" class="mw-redirect" title="Faeces" style="color: rgb(11, 0, 128); background-image: none; background-position: initial; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;faeces&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;. These organisms produce H&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;sub style="line-height: 1; font-size: 11.2px; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;2&amp;lt;/sub&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;S from thiosulfate and can be identified easily on differential media such as&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bismuth_sulfite_agar" title="Bismuth sulfite agar" style="color: rgb(11, 0, 128); background-image: none; background-position: initial; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;bismuth sulfite agar&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;.&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For better readability I have only used few lines of code from what you have added in your question.

If you can use regex to replace style from the html content. Here is a helpful piece of code, you can try this out:

```js
var str = '&amp;lt;span style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;In 1896 and named after its inventor,&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georges-Fernand_Widal" title="Georges-Fernand Widal" style="color: rgb(11, 0, 128); background-image: none; background-position: initial; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; fot-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;Georges-Fernand Widal&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;';
ret = str.replace(/style=".*?"/gm,'');
console.log(ret);
```

Anything inside `style="..."` will be removed by using this.

`g` in regex is used for global search in given string
`m` in regex for multi-line search

**Answer Updated:**

If you need to **Decode the above code as HTML format**, you can see below section:

```js
var str = '&amp;lt;span style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;In 1896 and named after its inventor,&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georges-Fernand_Widal" title="Georges-Fernand Widal" style="color: rgb(11, 0, 128); background-image: none; background-position: initial; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; fot-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;Georges-Fernand Widal&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;';
ret = str.replace(/style=".*?"/gm, '');
// console.log(ret);

var parser = new DOMParser;
var dom = parser.parseFromString(
  '<!doctype html><body>' + ret,
  'text/html');
var decodedString = dom.body.textContent;
// console.log(decodedString);

var actualHTML = $('<textarea />').html(decodedString).text();
console.log(actualHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Actually it's removing only inline style. I want to be like <p> <<content>> </p> not span and other tags and all any how thank you for kind help.

Comment: Do you want to replace all tags with `p` tag or to any specific ones?

Comment: Do you need to decode data to HTML form? like `&amp;lt;span &amp;gt;` to `<span>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Would like to see what you have tried till now

To remove inline style use `$("#Div").removeAttr("style");`

Comment: i have tried using regExp..like element.html().replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '').replace(/&nbsp;/g, '').replace(/<br>/gi, "\n") etc..

Answer (score 0):

I got it now, along with the styles you want to get rid of the unwanted html entities used and have its equivalent html code to be available to you.

If that is what you are looking for, below is the solution listed.

say below is the string you get from wikipedia,

```
var str = '&amp;lt;span style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;In 1896 and named after its inventor,&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georges-Fernand_Widal" title="Georges-Fernand Widal" style="color: rgb(11, 0, 128); background-image: none; background-position: initial; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; fot-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;Georges-Fernand Widal&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;, is a presumptive&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serological" class="mw-redirect" title="Serological" style="color: rgb(11, 0, 128); background-image: none; background-position: initial; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;serological&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;&amp;amp;nbsp;testfor&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enteric_fever" class="mw-redirect" title="Enteric fever" style="color: rgb(11, 0, 128); background-image: none; background-position: initial; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;enteric fever&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;&amp;amp;nbsp;or&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undulant_fever" class="mw-redirect" title="Undulant fever" style="color: rgb(11, 0, 128); background-image: none; background-position: initial; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;undulant fever&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;&amp;amp;nbsp;whereby bacteria causing tphoid and protozoa causing malaria fever are mixed with a serum containing specific antibodies obtained from an infected individual. In cases of&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;i style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salmonella" title="Salmonella" style="color: rgb(11, 0, 128); background-image: none; background-position: initial;"&amp;gt;Salmonella&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/i&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;&amp;amp;nbsp;infection, it is a demonstration of the presence of O-soma false-positive result. Test results need to be interpreted carefully to account for any history of enteric fever,&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typhoid" class="mw-redirect" title="Typhoid" style="color: rgb(11, 0, 128); background-image: none; background-position: initial; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;typhoid&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;&amp;amp;nbsp;vaccination, and the general level of antibodies in the populations in endemic areas of the world.&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typhidot" title="Typhidot" style="color: rgb(11, 0, 128); background-image: none; background-position: initial; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;Typhidot&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;&amp;amp;nbsp;is the other test used to ascertain the diagnosis of&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typhoid_fever" title="Typhoid fever" style="color: rgb(11, 0, 128); background-image: none; background-position: initial; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;typhoid fever&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;. As with all serological tests, the rise in antibody levels needed to perform the diagnosis takes 7–14 days, which limits its applicability in early diagnosis. Other means of diagnosing&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;i style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salmonella_typhi" class="mw-redirect" title="Salmonella typhi" style="color: rgb(11, 0, 128); background-image: none; background-position: initial;"&amp;gt;Salmonella typhi&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/i&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;&amp;amp;nbsp;(and&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;i style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salmonella_paratyphi" class="mw-redirect" title="Salmonella paratyphi" style="color: rgb(11, 0, 128); background-image: none; background-position: initial;"&amp;gt;paratyphi&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/i&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;) include cultures of blood, urine and&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faeces" class="mw-redirect" title="Faeces" style="color: rgb(11, 0, 128); background-image: none; background-position: initial; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;faeces&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;. These organisms produce H&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;sub style="line-height: 1; font-size: 11.2px; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;2&amp;lt;/sub&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;S from thiosulfate and can be identified easily on differential media such as&amp;amp;nbsp;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bismuth_sulfite_agar" title="Bismuth sulfite agar" style="color: rgb(11, 0, 128); background-image: none; background-position: initial; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;bismuth sulfite agar&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;"&amp;gt;.&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;';
```

the first thing you would have to do is get rid of the style attribute. you can use regex as below.

```
str = str.replace(/style=".*?"/gm,'');
```

Now parsing this string as a HTML document. For doing this you will have to either create a div element in DOM, and then assign this as the innerHTML to the created div element.

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = str;
var result = div.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
console.log(result);
```

In your console you will see the parsed HTML code.
Hope this will help!!

Comment: I have tried this it will remove only style not other malformed html.

Comment: I have edited the entire answer, please check the new solution.